# PHP Бан по IP/Аккаунту

Tags: php

**Мне нужно организовать бан по IP посредством PHP.
Прогулявшись по форумам я нашел примеры, они реализованы одним из двух способов:**

1. Через массив(хранить IP в массиве)
2. Файловый (хранить IP в текстовом файле)

Я хочу реализовать бан по IP, а так же бан по аккаунту. 
Собираюсь реализовать через бд *MySQL*. Хотел бы узнать какие недостатки мною выбранного метода.
 И как мне лучше реализовать. Может бан *по IP* на файлах, а бан *по аккаунту* в бд.

**Прошу совета тех, у кого есть опыт!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На уровне обращения к черному списку, система банов предполагает, что читаться этот самый список будет намного чаще, чем туда будет что-то записываться. СУБД используют самые эффективные алгоритмы для поиска информации в индексированных списках. Это особенно важно, если черный список будет очень большим.

Плюс, предполагаю что движок вашей системы работает с MySQL, аккаунты хранятся так-же, в базе. С БД работа уже налажена, и логичнее всего туда-же прикручивать остальную функциональность.

Если черный список будет не очень большим, то можно воспользоваться и файлами. Но, желательно, хранить его в виде сериализованного массива (функция *[serialize()](http://ua.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)*), обрабатываться будет быстрее. Плюс, с файлами вы работаете напрямую, а с базой через СУБД.

Как-то так...

**UPD:** Для работы с IP  в MySQL есть удобные функции [`INET_NTOA()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-ntoa) и [`INET_ATON()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton). Они преобразовывают строку с IP в число, и обратно. Список чисел обрабатывается быстрее чем список строк.

Comment: Я вот предположить хотел, но постеснялся - опыта нет. А вам не кажется, что в случае ДДОСа это не даст вообще никакого эффекта(база рухнет первой же)?

Comment: Ну, в случае крепкого ДДОСа, веб-сервер ляжет рядом с базой :)). Я так понял, человека интересует фильтр от обычных входов на сайт.

Comment: Защита от ДДОС дело не PHP. Это Сервер и иже с ним. Можно, конечно, выполнять системные вызовы и пихать из php банлист прямо в фаервол, но это вообще костыль.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант: Javascript код выполняется в браузерах, и не выполняется где-то ещё, копайте в эту сторону. Например, на некоторых неофициальных сайтах онлайн игр, поставлена простая защита от дос: "Нажмите на картинку чтобы перейти по ссылке". Реализуется это так :

```
<img src="img.jpg" onclick="gotolink()">
```

При клике по изображению произойдёт событие onclick и выполнит нашу функцию gotolink(), вот один из способов узнать, зашёл на сайт человек(браузер) или что-то другое либо таким же способом проверяем, выполнился код - значит браузер зашёл, не выполнился - значит не браузер. )

Comment: Что мешает написать бота, который будет сам отправлять нужные запросы, читать капчи и т.п.?

Comment: Пишите, а я напишу более совершенную защиту. )

Comment: Любой снифер покажет, куда ведет функция gotolink() и ничего вы не сделаете уже, подставить туда данные не составит труда.

Comment: Это понятно, а действия пользователя, события onclick onmousemove снифер может выполнить?

Comment: Какая разница были эти события или нет? После этих действий в браузере, что будет происходить?? Отсылка какого-то запроса на сервер? Что мешает мне его послать? Или генерация ссылки для перехода?? Что мне мешает взять скрипт генерации ссылки этой и сгенерить ее самому?

Все, что не придумано человеком, обходится.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант прикрутить еще и куки

Answer (score 0):

На мое мнение mysql быстрее и куда удобрение

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется наилучшим вариантом, будет при входе записывать ip адрес в куки, и делать проверку из файла, где находится список бан адресов. Чем меньше запросов к БД тем лучше, сами понимаете.